# How to make the imagebutton permanent even when moving out of the activity?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am trying to make an app where there are many cities and i want to add favorites cities. I am doing this by making a heart shaped button on the below of city's image. When the Favorites button is clicked, the button goes pink. Just like Instagram. But whenever I am moving out of the selected city, the button goes back to its normal state. And i want it to be selected as favorite.What I have done is that whenever the button is clicked it is added to favorites and when clicked again it is removed from favorites. Please. Can anybody help? here is my code CitySelectedActivity.java

```
 private String PICK_CITYSELECTED=" ";
private ImageView imageView;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private TextView mTextView;
private ViewPager viewPager;
//int[] mResources={R.drawable.manali,R.drawable.manali2,R.drawable.manali3,R.drawable.manali4};
CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
private static int currentpage=0;
private static int numpages=0;
private int[] img;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private TextView textView;
private ImageButton favouriteBtn;
private boolean showingFirst=true;
private SharedPreferences pref;








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_selected);
    mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    PICK_CITYSELECTED=intent.getExtras().getString("PICK_CITY");
    Toast.makeText(this, PICK_CITYSELECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final Boolean isFirstRun=getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstrun",true);
    favouriteBtn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonfav);
    favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like24);
    favouriteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(showingFirst==true)
           {
               getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstrun",false).apply();
               favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.likepink24);
               //showingFirst=false;
           }
           else
           {
               favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like24);
               showingFirst=true;
           }
        }
    });
```

Here is my code for Xml file activity_city_selected.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.srushtee.dummy.CitySelectedActivity"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator">

    </me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator>

</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/continue_booking"
        android:text="Continue Booking"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonfav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="205dp"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. make a new class file. I named it as ConstantNames.java**

**this is the code of ConstantNames.java file**

**(nameArrayList is a static so it will contain values after closing the app too)**

```
public class ConstantNames {
    public final static HashSet<String> nameArrayList=new HashSet<>();
}
```

**2. In Your MainActivity.java  =>  in onClickListener  =>  add the value into nameArrayList**

**This is the code to add values in nameArrayList**

**NOTE: HashSet contanins only unique values if you want dublicate values then you can use arraylist**

```
oneImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ConstantNames.nameArrayList.add("your_value_name");
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not getting it. how it will help?